# What SELinux context should the script have to be ran by pam_exec?

Tags: pam, selinux

I just installed Fedora 22 on my VPS and tried  to make trivial thing -- run my informer script on every ssh login via pam_exec.
But I was confronted with unexpected difficulties: pam_exec failed with exit code 13.

I added habitual line to the end of /etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/bin/loginformer.py
```

Of course loginformer.py has execution flags:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/loginformer.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4254 Jun  8 09:35 /usr/local/bin/loginformer.py
```

But here is painful extract from `journalctl -lb  SYSLOG_FACILITY=10`:

```
Jun 08 11:58:49 fedora22 sshd[671]: pam_exec(sshd:session): execve(/usr/local/bin/loginformer.py,...) failed: Permission denied
Jun 08 11:58:49 fedora22 sshd[663]: pam_exec(sshd:session): /usr/local/bin/loginformer.py failed: exit code 13
```

I'm not sure what's happening, because it always work on my ArchLinux.
I think it may be some SELinux resctriction, but I'm not sure.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Well, I tried to go deeply to SELinux and understood I should change SELinux context of my script.

Now SELinux context of it looks so:

```
$ ls -Z /usr/local/bin/loginformer.py
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 /usr/local/bin/loginformer.py
```

But which context should I set to the script?

**UPDATE 2**

Also, I think SELinux AVC logs may be very useful for detection of problem. I'm sorry I didn't give it earlier.
`cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep loginformer.py` return a lot of same strings:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1433784991.570:265): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=7866 comm="sshd" name="loginfomer.py" dev="vda1" ino=11924 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Comment: @Christopher "same context as the files that `loginformer.py` reads". But it doesn't read any files. It just get values of PAM enviroment variables (like `PAM_USER`), compose an email and send it via `smtplib`. Or python's `import ...` is "file read" from the point of view of SELinux?..

Comment: @Christopher also I attach extract from SELinux AVC log. As I can see, SELinux prohibited execute of script, not some file reading.

Comment: @Christopher yes, `setenforce 0` "fix" the problem and `loginformer.py` start and run normally. But I think it isn't a good idea.

Comment: I mean to say that `setenforce 0` is insecure and I think it isn't a good solution.

Comment: Yes, I understood. It worked. But I till now have no idea how explain SELinux that I want run this script from pam_exec. :(

Comment: Files created under `/usr/local/bin` on my system (Centos7) have context `unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0`. Try running `restorecon` on your script to set the correct context?

Answer (score 2):

The order in which `pam_exec` and `pam_selinux` are invoked is important. Man page for [`pam_selinux`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_selinux.8.html) notes:

> Adding pam_selinux into the PAM stack might disrupt behavior of other
>     PAM modules which execute applications. To avoid that, *pam_selinux.so
>     open* should be placed after such modules in the PAM stack, and
>     *pam_selinux.so close* should be placed before them. When such a
>     placement is not feasible, *pam_selinux.so restore* could be used to
>     temporary restore original security contexts.

Similarly, [Dan Walsh writes](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/18865.html) about the topic:

> If you are going to add a pam_module that would exec commands that the user would not be allowed to execute, for example pam_mount, it should be added **before** the pam_selinux.so open command.  If you are adding a pam_module that execs command a user could execute, then you probably want these **after** the pam_selinux.so open line.

Also note that your script currently has security context of `user_home_t`, which is not likely compatible with the default policy (file contexts are preserved when file is moved; if you created the file in your home directory moving the file will preserve the original context). You probably should use the default `bin_t` context. To restore the default context:

```
restorecon  /usr/local/bin/loginformer.py
```

If your script does not do anything too special, placing `pam_exec` before `pam_selinux` and restring the context should be enough to fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I do not already have the VPS so cannot check your answer. I assume it will not be proper if I accept the answer without it. Thank you for the verbose answer, I hope it will help someone else.